# How to load pop only once for a user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp-classic, popup

I have used the below code to load pop on Page load,i dont want it load everytime a user refreshes page

```
$(function () {
    var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    overlay.show();
    overlay.appendTo(document.body);
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $('.popup').show();

        $('.close').click(function(){
            $('.popup').hide();
            overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
            return false;
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) API is a pretty easy way to do this:

```
$(function () {
    if (window.localStorage.popupHasBeenShown)
        return; 

    var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    overlay.show();
    overlay.appendTo(document.body);
    $(document).ready(function() {

        window.localStorage.popupHasBeenShown = true;
        $('.popup').show();

        $('.close').click(function(){
            $('.popup').hide();
            overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Some people may prefer to use the [cookie API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), i.e. `window.document.cookie`, an advantage being that setting the expiry date is really easy—so you could, say, have the popup show up only once a week or so:

```
document.cookie = "doSomethingOnlyOnce=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
```

Comment: Hehe no prob! Accept the answer if it helped you pwease :-)

Comment: In this case pop up will not get showed to user even if  pop up has opened once.What if i have to set time frames after which pop up will be again shown @nikk wong